# How to insert the text at the begin of each line only if the given pattern matches in that line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I need to insert the text at each line only if the given pattern matches with that line.

For example,

```
      sed -n '/pattern/p' /etc/inittab/
```

so, if the pattern matches with any of the lines in inittab file, then i need to insert '#' at the beginning of those lines in the same file itself.

Kindly suggest me, how to make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved with the following `sed` invocation

```
% sed -i.orig -e '/pattern/s/^/#/' inittab
```

The `-i.orig` option tells `sed` to operate in place on the file, previously saving the original as `inittab.orig`. The editing pattern

```
/pattern/    selects lines matching pattern
s/^/#/       and substitute the empty word at the beginning of line with #
```

Comment: but attribute -i is not supporting in sun os.

Comment: @sivakumarV Then process your file and save the result in `inittab.edit` as with `sed -e '/pattern/s/^/#/' inittab > inittab.edit`, review your changes with diff and once you are confident that your new file is correct manually rename it.

Comment: Hi, Inserting the text at the beginning is working now. And i need to delete the first character of a line, only if pattern matches. Kindly help me to do this.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `sed`:

```
sed '/pattern/s/^/#/' file
```

This will look for lines matching the pattern and once it finds it, it will place `#` in front of it. This will not modify the file. In order to do so, you need to use `-i` option to make in-place changes. You can put an extension like `-i.bak` to make an optional back if you'd like.

#### Using `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/{$0="#"$0}1' file
```

`awk` is made up by pattern action statements. For the matching pattern, the action we do is modify the line by placing `#` in front of it. The `1` at the end will print the lines for us. GNU `awk` v4.1 or later has in-place editing just like `sed`. If you are using an older version you can redirect the output to another file and `mv` it back to original by saying:

```
awk '/pattern/{$0="#"$0}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

The in-place changes is nothing special. It does the same job as redirecting to a temp file and then moving it back. It just does all the dirty work for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Am getting error with awk command as awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @sivakumarV If you are on solaris be sure to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. The regular `awk` on solaris is broken.

Comment: As you suggested i have used the awk, but output is not as expected.                                        /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '/LYCAISR/{$0="#"$0}1' /etc/inittab/
input file "/etc/inittab/"bash-3.00$

Comment: @sivakumarV Doesn't the `sed` option working for you? You need to redirect the output to another file using `>`.

Comment: And i need to delete the first character of a line, only if pattern matches in that line. Kindly help me to do this.

Comment: @sivakumarV New requirements needs new question.